# Multiple .pst files for a single email

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

When I go to the location where my outlook .pst files are stored (*C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook)* I constantly seem to have multiples of my email accounts. Unfortunately, it's not just doubled, I usually get 3+ copies of each.

Is there a way to clean these up so I only have 1 .pst per email account or is there a reason I have so many of each? (I have gone through an deleted some & all of them, but once I reopen Outlook, they all come back)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check under your Account Settings.  Click the Data Files tab and it will list the PST files it is using for each account.

Once you know which PST files you are using, then delete the other ones.

Comment: I have tried that, but the minute I restart Outlook, they all come back.